# Help evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty}(x^n + y^n)^{1/(1-n)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I get $0$ when I do it by hand, but when i check mathematica I get $\frac{1}{\max\{x,y\}}$ (at least for the 4 or 5 cases I have checked so far).

Here is my work: Take natural log to get $\frac{1}{1-n} \ln(x^n + y^n)$, then L'hopital on that (I suspect this may be where I am wrong, as perhaps L'hopital doesn't apply?), giving $-\frac{n(x^{n-1}+y^{n-1})}{x^n + y^n}$

That then simplifies to $-n$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} -n = -\infty$, and $e^{-\infty} =0$

So how can I go about evaluating this limit? Specifically, since I do think that the answer should be $1/\max\{x,y\}$, how does $\max$ get involved?

Thanks.

Comment: L'hospitals rule is only one dimensional.

Comment: Are you given anything about $x$ and $y$, by any chance?

Comment: @Clarinetist They sum to $1$. And they must be nonnegative.

Comment: 1) The limit is on $n$, not on $x$. Had you wanted to use l'Hopital, you should have considered the function $t\mapsto \dfrac{\ln(x^t+y^t)}{1-t}$ and differentiate w.r.t. $t$  2) Your differentiation is wrong, because you applied $\frac{d}{dx}$ to $x^n$, $\frac{d}{dy}$ to $y^n$ and $\frac{d}{dn}$ to $1-n$... **Everybody** gets a derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $$A_n=(x^n + y^n)^{\frac 1 {1-n}}$$  suppose $x>y$ and set $y=\lambda x$ with $\lambda <1$.

So $$A_n=x^{\frac{n}{1-n}}(1+\lambda^n )^{\frac{1}{1-n}}$$ So, when $n$ becomes large, the first exponent tends to $-1$. Concerning the second term, since $n$ is large $\lambda^n\to 0$ and raised to a power going to $0$, it tends to $1$. All of this makes the limit to be $\frac 1x$.

Repeat the same process assuming now $y>x$ and get a limit equal to $\frac 1y$.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(x^n + y^n)^{\frac 1 {1-n}}=\frac{1}{\max\{x,y\}}$$

The fat that $x+y=1$ is not relevant.